# MooTools Chained Functions Won't Execute

Tags: mootools

I'm using MooTools and I've got the following code that I can't seem to get to execute.  I'm expecting it to increase the width of the `#bar` element to `50px`, then `alert()` with a "hi!", and then continue increasing the width of `#bar` to `200px`.  For whatever reason, it stops after "hi!" and won't continue to execute.  What's up?

```
var myFx = new Fx.Tween($('bar'), {
duration: '500ms',
transition: 'sine:out',
link: 'chain'
});

myFx.start('width', '50').chain(
function() { alert('hi!'); },
function() { myFx.start('width', '200'); }
);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nUWsU/7/)
​

Answer (score 7, accepted):

that's because your 2nd function does not call a method of the myFx class - which means, it won't advance the chain.

chain is a mixin into the Fx class. if you do an animation, it will auto try to `callChain`. since you do nothing of the sort, add this underneath the alert:

```
this.callChain();
```

this will work fine. perhaps the docs need changing as it's not obvious right now. http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/nUWsU/8/

Comment: Awesome, and yes, that makes sense.  I had wondered if that was the case (I had tried a handful of functions and it would only run through them if they were of the `myFx.start()` variant), but couldn't tell for sure.  While I have you on the horn, would you mind if I asked another question?  Does Fx.Tween support CSS3 styles like `border-radius`, `box-shadow`, etc.?  They don't seem to work for me either.

Comment: not atm. i would recommend doing a custom build of mootools without Fx and instead bundling Moo.Fx - example http://mootools.net/blog/2012/08/13/optimizing-mootools-builds-sans-internet-explorer/ - or grab from kamicane's repo. its for prime (mootools 2) but also standalone. else, you can use something like this https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/baseBox/blob/master/Source/baseBox.js#L26-45 to extend the Fx.CSS parser for props - or look on the Forge, http://mootools.net/forge/browse?search=css3 (via css3 if poss) or http://mootools.net/forge/p/fx_css for simple props parsing.

Comment: A handful of excellent resources, and great ideas!  Very much appreciated! :)